# Python SQLAlchemy attribute-events - How to check oldvalue equals NO_VALUE?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The [official documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#attribute-events) of SQLAlchemy states:

> oldvalue – the previous value being replaced. This may also be the
>   symbol `NEVER_SET` or `NO_VALUE`. If the listener is registered with
>   `active_history=True`, the previous value of the attribute will be
>   loaded from the database if the existing value is currently unloaded
>   or expired.

```
from sqlalchemy import event

# standard decorator style
@event.listens_for(SomeClass.some_attribute, 'set')
def receive_set(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    "listen for the 'set' event"

    # ... (event handling logic) .
```

My problem is how can I check the old value equals the symbol `NO_VALUE`?

M use `if oldvalue == symbol(NO_VALUE)`  but it gives me error.

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: `if oldvalue is NO_VALUE`?

Comment: @univerio oldvalue is NO_VALUE works... thanks..you can post it as a answer..  also remember to from sqlalchemy.orm.base import NO_VALUE

Answer (score 6):

use

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.base import NO_VALUE
if oldvalue is NO_VALUE:
    //login here
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `if oldvalue is symbol('NO_VALUE'):`